# updating only decimal with trailing zero

Tags: python, pandas

How can we update only the decimal values of the column with trailing zeros if there are only one digit after decimal.

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.3, 0.3], [0.5, 1], [0.400, 0.4], [0.2, 5],[1.2, 1.55]],
    columns=['credit', 'min_credit'])
```

Executing the below code changes the int as well

```
df[min_required_credit] = df[min_credit].map('{:.2f}'.format)
```

Expected result:

| credit | min_credit |
| --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0.30 |
| 0.5 | 1 |
| 0.400 | 0.40 |
| 0.2 | 5 |
| 1.2 | 1.55 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post-process with a simple regex and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['min_credit'].map('{:.2f}'.format).str.replace(r'\.0+$', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
0    0.30
1       1
2    0.40
3       5
4    1.55
Name: min_credit, dtype: object
```

With assignment:

```
df['min_required_credit'] = (df['min_credit']
                             .map('{:.2f}'.format)
                             .str.replace(r'\.0+$', '', regex=True)
                            )
```

output:

```
   credit  min_credit min_required_credit
0     0.3        0.30                0.30
1     0.5        1.00                   1
2     0.4        0.40                0.40
3     0.2        5.00                   5
4     1.2        1.55                1.55
```

regex:

```
\.    # a literal dot
0+    # one or more 0
$     # the end of line
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.3, 0.3], [0.5, 1], [0.400, 0.4], [0.2, 5],[1.2, 1.55]], columns=['credit', 'min_credit'])
def stringify(x):
    return '{:.2f}'.format(x) if x%1 else '{:.0f}'.format(x)
df['min_credit'] = df['min_credit'].apply(stringify)
print(df)
```

output

```
   credit min_credit
0     0.3       0.30
1     0.5          1
2     0.4       0.40
3     0.2          5
4     1.2       1.55
```

Explanation: if rest of division by `1` is non-zero this is non-integer else it is integer, depending on that either format as `.2f` (2 digits after `.`) or `.0f` (no digits after `.`). Logic is encased in function, which is applied to selected column.